# Accessing training data during tensorflow graph execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to use pre-trained sentence embeddings in my tensorflow graph execution model. The embeddings are available dynamically from a function call, which takes in an array of sentences and outputs an array of sentence embeddings. This function uses a pre-trained pytorch model so has to remain separate from the tensorflow model I'm training:

```
def get_pretrained_embeddings(sentences):
  return pretrained_pytorch_model.encode(sentences)
```

My tensorflow model looks like this:

```
class SentenceModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
  def call(self, sentences):
    embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    10_000,
    256,
    embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(get_pretrained_embeddings(sentences)),
    trainable=False,
  )
  sentence_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
    embedding_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  ])
  return sentence_text_embedding,
```

But when I try to train this model using

```
cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(1024)
model.fit(cached_train)
```

my embeddings_initializer call gets the error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

I assume this is because tensorflow is trying to compile the graph using symbolic data. How can I get my external function, which relies on the current training data batch, to work with tensorflow's graph training?

Comment: The `call` function is for forwarding passes. I think you should set `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` and `tf.keras.Sequential` in the `init` method.

Comment: Provide some reproducible plug-n-play code to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow compiles models to an execution graph before performing the actual training process. The obvious side-effect that clues us into this is if we have a regular Python `print()` statement in e.g. our `call()` method, **it will only get executed once** as Tensorflow runs through your code to construct the execution graph, which it will later convert to native code.

The other side effect of this is that **cannot use anything that isn't a tensor of some description when training**. By 'tensor' here, all of the following can be considered a tensor:

- The input value of your `call()` method (obviously)
- A `tf.Sequential`
- A `tf.keras.Model`/`tf.keras.layers.Layer` subclass
- A `SparseTensor`
- A `tf.constant()`
- ....probably more I haven't listed here.

To this end, you would need to convert your PyTorch model to a Tensorflow one to be able to reference it in a subclass of `tf.keras.Model`/`tf.keras.layers.Layer`.

---

As a side note, if you *do* find you need to iterate a tensor, you should just be able to iterate it on the 1st dimension (i.e. the batch size) like so:

```py
for part in some_tensor:
    pass
```

If you want to iterate on some other dimension, I recommend doing a `tf.unstack(some_tensor, axis=AXIS_NUMBER_HERE)` first and iterate over the result thereof.